# django db with ssh tunnel

Tags: python, django, ssh-tunnel

Is there a python native way to connect django to a database through an ssh tunnel? I have seen people using ssh port forwarding in the host machine but I would prefer a solution that can be easily containerized.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is pretty seamless.

**Requirements:**
The `sshtunnel` package https://github.com/pahaz/sshtunnel

1. In the django `settings.py` create an ssh tunnel before the django DB settings block:

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

# Connect to a server using the ssh keys. See the sshtunnel documentation for using password authentication
ssh_tunnel = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    SERVER_IP,
    ssh_private_key=PATH_TO_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY,
    ssh_private_key_password=SSH_PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD,
    ssh_username=SSH_USERNAME,
    remote_bind_address=('localhost', LOCAL_DB_PORT_ON_THE_SERVER),
)
ssh_tunnel.start()
```

2. Then add the DB info block in the `settings.py`. Here I am adding a default local DB and the remote DB that we connect to using the ssh tunnel

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'HOST': NORMAL_DB_HOST,
        'PORT': NORMAL_DB_PORT,
        'NAME': NORMAL_DB_NAME,
        'USER': NORMAL_DB_USER,
        'PASSWORD': NORMAL_DB_PASSWORD,
    },
    'shhtunnel_db': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': ssh_tunnel.local_bind_port,
        'NAME': REMOTE_DB_DB_NAME,
        'USER': REMOTE_DB_USERNAME,
        'PASSWORD': REMOTE_DB_PASSWORD,
    },
}
```

That is it. Now one can make migratations to the remote db using commands like `$ python manage.py migrate --database=shhtunnel_db` or make calls to the db from within the python code using lines like `Models.objects.all().using('shhtunnel_db')`

**Extra:**
In my case the remote db was created by someone else and I only wanted to read it. In order to avoid writing the models and deactivating the model manager I used the following django command to get the models from the database [[src](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/legacy-databases/)]:

```
python manage.py inspectdb
```

Comment: Could please post an example for the `default` DB connection? I want to connect Django's  `default` DB to a remote DB using SSH tunnel.

Comment: I guess using the ssh tunnel db configurations under the `default` key would work as expected

Comment: If you could please post an example for the same. I have the pem file, but no password is required for SSH tunnel. If I'm passing a blank password. Then, it's failing to authenticate. Our SSH tunnel doesn't require password to connect just a pem file. I was able to connect on command line using the pem file and SSH command.

Comment: I am getting error 'django.utils.connection.ConnectionDoesNotExist: The connection 'sshtunnel_db' doesn't exist.' any ideas?

Comment: @DavidHenson Are you able to connect to the db with the same inputs from lets say pg4admin or a similar software?

Comment: Great! It works on MS-Windows. I can't connect to SSH server by its domain name. Only work with IP address.

Comment: It is hosted on pypi so use `pip install sshtunnel` to install it.